# Selecting first of many rows using SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to extract specific rows from a MSSQL database. For a given combination of `DistCode` and `RtrId`, I want to select only the first row appearing in the table, with the latest date. The table has 5 columns - DistCode (w/ a 7-digit entry), RtrId (w/ a 4 digit entry), X (w/ String), Class (w/String) and CreatedDate (w/yyyy-mm-dd). Sorry my formatting sucks - trying to do this the first time.

From the table below, I would ideally like to select only row#2 i.e. since it has the latest date and also happens to the be sequentially the first among CreatedDate options.

```
DistCode    RtrId   X   Class   CreatedDate
1001885     5085    GT  BR      16-07-17
```

The table data looks like this:

```
DistCode    RtrId   X   Class   CreatedDate
1001885     5085    GT  BR  2016-03-05
1001885     5085    GT  BR  2016-07-17
1001885     5085    GT  OT  2016-07-17
1001885     5085    GT  BR  2016-05-05
```

```
dr1=select([dr.c.DistCode, dr.c.RtrId, dr.c.X, dr.c.Class, func.max(dr.c.CreatedDate).label('latest_Date')]).group_by(dr.c.DistCode, dr.c.RtrId, dr.c.X , dr.c.Class).distinct()
```

Using func.max in SQLAlchemy Core, I am able to filter down to rows 2 and 3, but how do  I further recover only row#2. Kindly provide inputs using SqlAlchemy Core only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a probably not-so-efficient way of doing this, by first converting the sql database into a pandas dataframe, and then using the groupby and first() method to filter my data.

I only wish there was a func.first() first option in SQL.

Those to all who helped edit my question and for those who tried to crack it within SQLAlchemy Core.

Comment: You could set a `limit(1)`